# The graph of $|z−a|+|z+a|=2|c|$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am wondering how to draw the graph of $|z−a|+|z+a|=2|c|$. Do I need to consider several different conditions? Would the graph be different? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the defining characteristic of the ellipse: the sum of the distances from the two focii is constant. In particular, said sum is twice the semi-major axis.

This is what you essentially have. In all generality if $a = \alpha + i \beta $, where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ then

$$z = x + iy$$
$$|z - a| = \sqrt{(x - \alpha)^2 + (y - \beta)^2} = d[(x,y), (\alpha, \beta)] \qquad |z + a| = \sqrt{(x + \alpha)^2 + (y + \beta)^2} = d[(x,y), (-\alpha, -\beta)]$$

So we get that

$$d[(x,y), (\alpha, \beta)] + d[(x,y), (-\alpha, -\beta)] = 2|c|$$

But $2|c|$ is a real constant, and our definition of the ellipse implies that the semi-major axis is then equal to $|c|$ in length. So try drawing an ellipse with focii at the points $z = a$ and $z = -a$, with semi-major axis of length $|c|$.

Comment: So the semi-minor axis is of length $|c|^2-a^2$?

Comment: Is it true that the smallest value of $z$ is $-c$, and the largest is $c$?

Comment: In reference to the semi-minor axis, yes, but it looks like you are assuming that a is real. You can prove this fact by taking the point on the ellipse directly above or below the origin (again assuming a is real).

What do you mean by "smallest"? If z is complex, then it has no ordering. With respect to maybe the left most and right most points, then yes that is correct. Take a look at this:

https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/conics/ellipse.gif

In that link the variables a and c are switched based on your set up.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620685/absolute-value-equality-involving-complex-analysis, but there is a different answer here.

Comment: In that post they are talking about $|z|$, not $z$ itself, which is why my previous comment addressed the "leftmost" and "rightmost". In that case, the minimum value of $|z|$ is the minumum of $|c|$ or $\sqrt{c^2 - a^2}$. This is because (as stated in that post), the minima and maxima of $|z|$ occur along the endpoints of the semi-major and minor axes (these two axes are not the same).

Comment: So how to come to the conclusion of the smallest value and the largest value of the absolute value of z, according to the graph?

Comment: I thought they are supposed to be the same.